# Prevent the entering of users that have entered the wrong password more than 3 times

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to prevent entering of the users that have entered their password more than three times. I save their IP in session and set time-out for one minute. I don't know if this solution is good or not but there is a problem when wrong password is entered for three times. The code works correctly but, when the session times out, if I don't refresh the page it's not work. The user should be able to try again, but if I refresh it, the user can try again. What's the problem?

Here is my code...

```
 if (olduser.Trim() == username.Trim() && password.Trim()==oldpass.Trim())
        { retval =olduser;
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        context.Session[retval.ToString()] = retval.ToString();
       }
        else
        { 
            string ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
           HttpContext failuser = HttpContext.Current;
           failuser.Session.Timeout =1;
           if (failuser.Session[ip] != null)
               failuser.Session[ip] = (int)failuser.Session[ip] + 1;
           else
               failuser.Session[ip] = 1;
               retval = failuser.Session[ip].ToString();
               if((int)failuser.Session[ip]>2)
                retval = "!";                                 
        }

        return retval;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably trying to reinvent the wheel. Consider using a built in [ASP.NET Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you use a membership provider you get this functionality for free:

[Max Invalid Password Attempts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.maxinvalidpasswordattempts.aspx)